Error when using pdfinfo tool on AWS S3 presigned URL
I have uploaded a PDF to AWS S3 and generated a presigned URL for the PDF. I am able to paste the URL in my browser and the PDF renders as I would expect. However, when I attempt to use the pdfinfo tool to get information about the PDF using the presigned URL, I get the error Internal Error: Failed to initialize file cache. When I download the PDF using curl and then use the pdfinfo tool on the downloaded file, it works fine which makes me think it has something to do with how S3 is serving the PDF. Here are the headers returned when I curl -i the presigned URL:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: iYdZ3Bv46f7QU8US3kDMNMMsGiPbWUWOEs898tUfnczfOJTDt4LDV+qrOT/I0DI6Ct5tnyIA4R0=
x-amz-request-id: 1Y3M6J8JEFG8EWRS
Date: Tue, 31 Dec 2024 00:33:14 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 31 Dec 2024 00:25:05 GMT
ETag: "2bd227682ddb17d259d48455a8b9d951"
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
Content-Disposition: inline
x-amz-version-id: xzcpAfDCP3v2S7khPqnPQ.ODrkyXCZrU
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 885323
Server: AmazonS3

